# Searching by row in PowerShell array

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I have a function that creates an multi-dimensional array for a list of servers we are preparing for decommission. The array will have a number of fields such as server name, number of CPUs, Memory, Storage on the SAN, etc. etc. If it does not find the information it is looking for in one system, such as vCenter, it will look in a secondary system such as A.D. or a CMDB. All of this is working as intended.

What I am looking for is an efficient way to cycle through each row in the array, and then through each index of that row, looking for null or blank items. For example, if it comes back for server FileSrv018 that the IP address is blank, I want to prompt the user to manually enter this info. I could write a bunch of if statements, i.e.:

```
if ($row.CPU -eq $null) {

}
elseif ($row.IP -eq $null) {

}
```

... but I really don't want to go through that hassle. I am just curious if I there is a way to give me each "column" (I realize arrays don't really have column names) in a foreach loop. I can do it with a PSObject like so:

```
$columns = $decom.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

but have yet to find something similar with an array. Just curious if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: "I have a function that creates an multi-dimensional array for a list of servers" - why not rewrite that function to return objects instead?

Comment: I think you could use an enumerator on the properties and check for null if that's the way you want to do it, but methinks @MathiasR.Jessen's idea would certainly be easier

Comment: This is a multifunctional script, one function is returning an object per server and spins off into different modules depending on whether it is physical or virtual, whether it is 2008 or 2012 or 2016, etc. It seemed easier at the time to start with blank arrays and then, as the object is returned and the logic decides what to do with it next, populate the appropriate array. Some of the later modules accept the entire array as a parameter. I will probably rewrite it to use only objects if I cannot accomplish what I am after with the current code.

Comment: @JLogan3o13 Can you please post a sample array with values? If you can't share the function that generates it, just share a simple statement to recreate it, [like this](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/2d7c9b3dc7bea587855f2fdbd1da4d5f)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information in your post to give a definitive answer (please edit your post with the code with which you got the `$decom` value), but in general, the answer is: yes, sure, you can loop through all values of a multi-dimensional array in PowerShell easily:

```
$2DArray = New-Object 'System.Object[,]' 5,5

# populate $2DArray
# ...

for($i = 0; $i -lt $2DArray.GetLength(0); $i++){
  for($j = 0; $j -lt $2DArray.GetLength(1); $j++){
    if($null -eq $2DArray[$i,$j]){
      $2DArray[$i,$j] = Read-Host "Data missing in field $i,$j - please input data"
    }
  }
}
```

---

The procedure for iterating over a *jagged* array (aka a *nested* array) is almost the same:

```
$NestedArray = New-Object 'System.Object[][]' 5,5

# populate $NestedArray (remember to manually instantiate the inner arrays)
# ...

for($i = 0; $i -lt $NestedArray.Length; $i++){
  for($j = 0; $j -lt $NestedArray[$i]Length; $j++){
    if($null -eq $NestedArray[$i][$j]){
      $NestedArray[$i][$j] = Read-Host "Data missing in field $i,$j - please input data"
    }
  }
}
```